# save text from textbox in visual studio to excel cell

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013

I have few Textboxes in my form and I want to save the data they Contains into excel.
How can I make new excel file and save the data to the excel cell?
How do you determine what information will be transferred to each cell in Excel?

Thank you all

p.s
I'm using Visual Basic with Visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1):

If you're in excel vb and you're in the form code, you can do this:

thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = me.textBoxName.value

It'll copy whatever is in the textbox to sheet1 of the current workbook in cell A1.

You can play around with it to customize it to your needs.  Outside of the form, you'll need to replace me with the form name.